# Post a Game Request using JS / PHP

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs, xfbml

Is it possible to post a Game Request using the Facebook Javascript or PHP SDK?

I'm looking for something similar to streamPublish but for the Request channel. AFAIK the only methods i've found involve using FBML. I'd like a more extensible means than fb:request-form

Comment: Well, you can be creative and post to your friends' walls a URL with an invite code.

Answer (score 1):

No. Facebook does this deliberately to prevent application spam. The only way an app is allowed to send invites is through direct user interaction through the FBML elements.